# Using a regex in the custom field of Filebeat

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, filebeat

[Here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/configuration-filebeat-options.html#configuration-fields) I can read that when configuring a prospect I can add a custom field to the data, which later I can use for filtering.

So for example I can write

```
- type: log
  paths:
    - /my/path/app1.csv
  fields:
    app_name: app1
- type: log
  paths:
    - /my/path/app2.csv
  fields:
    app_name: app2
```

This means that anytime I will have a new CSV file to track I have to add it to the `filebeat.yml` file adding the custom `app_name` field accordingly.

I was wondering if I could use a regex with a capture group in the prospect definition to "automatically" track any new file and assign the right `app_name` value. Something like this:

```
- type: log
  paths:
    - /my/path/(.*).csv
  fields:
    app_name: \1
```

What do you think? I didn't find any [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/regexp-support.html) regarding this possibility with the `fields` feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As adviced [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/using-a-regex-in-the-custom-field-of-filebeat/126252), I can use the `source` Filebeat field to filter the data. This field is the path of the harvested files, so no other field is required to filter.